# Sequence generator and surrogate ID column for @@ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to simplify my current entity model for storing a user's old password* for preventing reuse.

For simplicity, I omitted most annotation attributes.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;


    ....

    @OneToMany
    @OrderBy("id desc")
    private List<OldPassword> oldPasswords;

}

@Entity
@Table
@SequenceGenerator
public class OldPassword {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Column
    private String oldPassword;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to delete the `OldPassword` class and actually embed it into the `User` class, as the `List<String>` it should naturally be.

There is a problem with this association. I **must** order the passwords in their reverse chronological order. I mean I can't simply have a table with (`USER_ID`,`OLD_PASSWORD`) columns, because I would miss ordering. I need the `OLD_PASSWORDS` table to show the following columns: `ID` (autoincrement), `USER_ID`, `OLD_PASSWORD`.

I have tried the following

```
@JsonIgnore
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        targetClass = String.class)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_STORE",
        sequenceName = "SEQ_OLD_PASSWORDS")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator = "SEQ_STORE")
@CollectionTable(name = "XTB_OLD_PASSWORDS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID",
                nullable = false) ,
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_XTB_OLDPWD_2_USR") )
@Column(name = "PASSWORD",
        nullable = false,
        length = 100)
@OrderBy("OLD_PASSWORD_ID desc")
@OrderColumn(name = "OLD_PASSWORD_ID",
        nullable = false)
private final List<String> oldPasswords = new ArrayList<>();
```

But when I create the schema I get the `hibernate_sequence` in Oracle and that the primary key is made both by `USER_ID` and `OLD_PASSWORD_ID`.

I must (for backwards compatibility issues) obtain `OLD_PASSWORD_ID` as only primary key **and** a proper Oracle sequence.

In JPA, how do I define an `@ElementCollection` that has its own surrogate, auto-incremented primary key that also serves for total ordering the `List`? As a recall, one can't use a `List` without an `@OrderBy` or `@OrderColumn` annotation on the collection, otherwise Hibernate doesn't know how to order elements. In absence of order column one must use a `Set` which is unordered.

*Security note before somebody comments on that: I store passwords encrypted!!!

Comment: An ElementCollection does NOT have its own surrogate id. It uses the ID of the owning object. All part of O-O